# Declaring date in plsql procedure and getting error

Tags: oracle, plsql

i dont know what is the error in the select statement....

```
create or replace procedure sampl_proc 
is
startdate DATE;
begin
select tick_date into startdate from utv.tick where tick_date= ('16/05/2017 09:00:09' , 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss');
dbms_output.put_line(startdate);
end;
```

and the error is:`[Error] ORA-01797 (5: 62): PL/SQL: ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL`

Comment: The should be tagged Oracle, not MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

### try this (to_date func)

```
 create or replace procedure sampl_proc 
is
startdate DATE;
begin
select tick_date into startdate from utv.tick where tick_date= to_date('16/05/2017 09:00:09' , 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss');
dbms_output.put_line(startdate);
end;
```

Comment: yes it has executed ........... now i have to set a input  parameter for startdate and execute the final output but it is not getting the output ............can u tell me how to do that

Comment: you should enable dbms output

Comment: i have done that too..... but still getting an error... :ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "UTV.SAMPL_PROC", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1